# Apps Script Security

Tags: java, android-studio, google-apps-script, http-get

I am creating an app in Android Studio that gets data from a Google spreadsheet. The app sends an HTTP GET request to an Apps Script. The Apps Script returns a JSON object containing data from the spreadsheet.

I have gotten this to successfully work with the deployment settings being:
Execute as: Me
Who has access: Anyone

The data that the Apps Script returns is sensitive, so I would like to restrict access to the script. To do this, I want the deployment settings to be:
Execute as: Me
Who has access: Only Myself

Below is the code I am using to call the GET request:

```
   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,SCRIPT_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i("response",response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }
        );
```

The Google Doc below is what I receive from the GET request when I have the deployment settings Execute as: Me
Who has access: Only Myself. The emulator phone that I am using for testing is logged into the same Google account as the Apps Script.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/11wxFDyoSz_PCeew8UAkzq_FvSOLxjkkIM3Fu8DuLmxM/edit?usp=sharing

How do I get the script to run with these deployment settings?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do you get the script to run with the deployment settings being: 
Execute as: Me
Who has access: Only Myself

Comment: Do you have the script published as a web app?

Comment: yes, I do have it published as a web app

Comment: What's the return code of the API call? 401 Unauthorized?

Comment: The status code is 200, but the link below has what gets passed into the onResponse function. When I give anyone access, it works properly. I get the JSON object in string form.https://docs.google.com/document/d/11wxFDyoSz_PCeew8UAkzq_FvSOLxjkkIM3Fu8DuLmxM/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: Can you try calling the API with Postman/curl and see what happens? It seems like an authorization issue but it's confusing that Apps Script is returning 200.

Comment: I am getting 200 for both in postman

Comment: Hmm, then I'm stumped as well. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters) makes it clear that a program can call the GET endpoint in Apps Script, but doesn't describe how to pass some authentication token to it.